# The results of optimizer.apply_gradients() is None

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

I am trying to apply an extra step -- let say a simple multiplication -- on the gradients with respect to a subset of trainable variables. Here's what have:

```
def do_something(tgvt):
new_tgvt = []
for gv in tgvt:
    if gv[0] == None:
        sh = tf.shape(gv[1])
        gv0 = tf.zeros(sh)
        gv0t = tf.convert_to_tensor(gv0)
        new_tgvt.append((gv0t, gv[1]))
    else:
        new_tgvt.append((gv[0]*5, gv[1]))

return new_tgvt

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 1e-5)
params = tf.trainable_variables()
pars = [params[27], params[29]]
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost,pars)
tgv = [(g,v) for (g,v) in gradients]

new_gradients = do_something(tgv)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(new_gradients)

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
total_iterations = 0  # record the total iterations
for i in range(total_iterations,total_iterations + num_iterations):
    x_batch, y_batch = data.train.next_batch(batch_size)
    feed_dict = {X: x_batch, y_true: y_batch, keep_prob: 0.5}
    result = session.run([train_op, pars], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

when I print the `result`, the gradients is `None`:

```
print(result[0])
print((result[1][0]).shape)      
print((result[1][1]).shape)

None
(5, 5, 1, 36)
(5, 5, 36, 64)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From docs :
`train_op` should return :

> An Operation that applies the specified gradients.

Calling `sess.run` on `train_op` is expected to give `None` because this Operation does not result in value rather it applies.

Why don't you check it yourself by printing old and updated value for one of the variables??

Comment: Oh then I just misunderstood the apply_gradients step and what it does. I checked the variables's value before and after change and it is as i expected to be. But, I thought that I should see the new ingredients as the result of the apply_gradients(). Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Docs are always helpful.